# Can i end a if statement in python from registering?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

The idea of this program is to serve as a little game for the kids at school, the problem is that if you anwser , the question with any of the if statements it will shoot to that level , run the app and you will get an idea , for example the answer to the last level is 146466 , this will allow kids to skip all the way to the end  ,  any improvements?any way we can format this differently , im aware there might be a whole new structure.

```
#For The the {Pha<n>tex} eyes  only 





#Tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


#Window 

root = Tk()
#Procedure that contains instructions to our game 
def answers(a):
                                                #answer level  1 , change to number 2 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '1000'or AnswerBox.get()== '1,000':

                                LEVEL.configure(text= 'Level : 2')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 1000 + 250')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')


                                                #answer to  level 2 , change to number 3 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '1250'or AnswerBox.get() == '1,250':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 3')

                                Question.configure(text = 'what is 2000 + 900')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                                                #answer to level 3 , change to number 4 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '2900'or AnswerBox.get()=='2,900' :

                                 LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 4')

                                 Question.configure(text = 'What is 2434 + 1009')
                                 AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                                                #answer to level 4 , change to number 5 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '3443'or AnswerBox.get() =='3,443':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 5')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 3020 + 2304')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                                                #answer level  5 , change to number 6 question

          if AnswerBox.get() == '5324'or AnswerBox.get() =='5,324':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 6')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 4291 + 2334')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                              #answer to level 6 , change to number 7 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '6625'or AnswerBox.get() =='6,625':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 7')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 56233 + 2334')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                              #answer to level 7, change to number 8 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '58567'or AnswerBox.get() =='58,567':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 8')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 56243 + 23674')

                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')

                                                        #answer to level 8 , change to number 9 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '79917'or AnswerBox.get() =='79,917':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 9')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 53403 + 82310')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                              #answer to level 9 , change to number 10 question
          if AnswerBox.get() == '135713'or AnswerBox.get() =='135,713':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'Level : 10')

                                Question.configure(text = 'What is 56233 + 90233')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')
                              #answer to level 10, You Win :)
          if AnswerBox.get() == '146,466'or AnswerBox.get() =='146466':

                                LEVEL.configure(text = 'You Have Finished :)')

                                Question.configure(text = 'You Are An  Genius Panther -{Pha<n>tex}')
                                AnswerBox.delete(0 , 'end')





#Procedure that allows us to jump back to level 1
def restart(event):
        Question.configure(text = 'What is 500 + 500')
        LEVEL.configure(text ='Level : 1')





#Level Entry
LEVEL = Label(root, text ='Level : 1' , font = ' times  10 bold' )
LEVEL.grid(row  = 0 , column = 0 ,sticky =W)
#Default start off question 
Question = ttk.Label(root , text = 'What is 500 + 500' , font = ' times 10 bold')
Question.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = W)




#Anwser Entry

AnswerBox = ttk.Entry(root)
AnswerBox.grid(row  = 2 , column = 0 , columnspan = 2 , sticky = W)




# submit Button 

submit = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Submit' )
submit.grid(row  = 2, column = 2  , sticky = W)
submit.bind('<Button-1>' , answers)

#Restart button
Restart  = ttk.Button(root , text = 'Restart')
Restart.grid(row = 2 , column = 3 , sticky = W)
Restart.bind('<Button-1>' , restart)

#Allowing our window to consistanly Loop through
root.mainloop()
```

The problem in this structure seems to be the boolean logic , meaning if any of the statements are true the code will run and i cannot figure out a way to create a Math game with "levels' so to speak picking and choosing what code runs  , im sure its fairly simple and im just over thinking it , this code will shoot the user to the level if the number matches , meaning its a bad bug if students want to just shoot to the end by entering 146466

Comment: To run this code you might have to remove the photo and icon , seeing as though its not included on ur drive

Comment: Maybe you can set a variable which contains the current level and verify it.

Comment: set a variable and say if the answers is correct level +=1 and change question to a different question corresponding to the level?

Comment: It's one solution. But I think I would make something like creating a dict with the key corresponding to the level and the value would be the result of the level.

Comment: thats what i was thinking , and kind of make a forloop , that configure the labels

Comment: This is way too much code. Please reduce it down to a [mcve]

Comment: just reduced it , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an example of what I mean in my last comment about the dict. I would make something like:

```
resLevel = { 1: 42, 
             2: 560 }
```

And then I would use `rightAnswer = resLevel.get(currentLevel)`

Make a function which check the answer:

```
def check(rightAnswer, answerGiven):
    if rightAnswer == answerGiven:
        return True
    return False
```

Just adapt the function check to what you want if you need a coma in it.

And to finish, get the value of the function check. If it's True then increment your current level and if it's False then just show a message on your interface to say it's false and let the value currentLevel as it is.

Comment: i fixed it lol , but thank you :) its people like you that make me get better

Comment: Your welcome. Don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted to close the post if you think it is. And if you need more precision, don't hesitate to ask in comment :)

Comment: dictionary containing the level and the answer to the level , then check that checks to see if the answer matches what is being submited , then return a boolean , then we need instructions to give the program as to how to change the level and question basiclly